# Озвучення слова Élysée

Tags: переклад

Élysée - французьке (?) слово, зустрічається в декількох комбінаціях ([лінк](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysee_(disambiguation))).
Найчастіше згадують Élysée Palace - палац Елізе (Елізейський? палац), резиденція президента Франції.

Чи якось унормовано озвучення Élysée?

Всі мавпують рос. варіант - Єлісейський (палац), який можливо є нормою для "сусідів", але не зовсім (нмд) вписується в норми української мови.

Отже, пропоную свої варіанти:

1. Елізейський
2. Елізський (трохи важче вимовляти :))

Comment: Гарне питання! Трохи не за темою, але зауважу, що зовсім не важко вимовляти "Елізський", адже приголосні звуки в українській мові асимілюють, тобто має вимовлятися "Елізький", це дуже просто:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Якщо копати до першоджерела назви, то мусять бути "Елісійський" або "Елізійський" - принаймні, так воно звучить в українських існуючих перекладах давньогрецької чи то давньоримської літератури.

Цитати:

- [Вергілій «Енеїда» (переклад М. Білика)](http://ae-lib.org.ua/texts/vergilius__aeneis__ua.htm):

  > [Книга V, 733–735] Не в Тартарі я нечестивім перебуваю, між тіней сумних, а в **Елісії**, світлім богоугодних зібранні.
  >
  > [Книга VI, 540–543] Ось оте місце, де шлях цей на дві поділився дороги: та, що праворуч, веде аж до мурів великого Діта, це до **Елісія** путь нам; а та, що ліворуч, карає й до нечестивого Тартару грішників тіні провадить.
  >
  > [Книга VI, 743–477] Тоді на простори **Елісія** шлють нас; і не багато нас тут пробуває на радісних нивах; доки аж довгий наш день, коли круг свій віки вже обійдуть, плям не очистить, що в нас повростали, й не лишиться чистий дух з нас, ефірний, вогонь із небесного первня.
  >
  > <sub>[Короткий зміст книги VI у примітках] В **Елісії**, країні вічного блаженства, Анхіс викладає синові своє вчення про очищення і переселення душ і показує йому нащадків-славетних римлян, починаючи з Ромула, засновника Рима, і кінчаючи Марцеллом, племінником і зятем Августа.</sub>
- [Фрідріх Шіллер «Елізій» (переклад Миколи Лукаша)](https://books.google.com/books?id=jTBGBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT53):

  > Забудьмо жалі і тривоги!
  > **Елізія** світлі чертоги
  > всяк радісним серцем стрічай!
  > Життя тут — саме благоденство,
  > вічна утіха, вічне блаженство,
  > в квітучому лузі співучий ручай.

  <sub>Цитату Шиллера/Лукаша додав [Sasha](/u/4); в оригінальних коментарях автора відповіді натомість було написано «а ще словника: [https://books.google.com/books?hl=uk&id=ntVPAAAAYAAJ&q=елісій»](https://books.google.com/books?hl=uk&id=ntVPAAAAYAAJ&q=%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%C2%BB) — але це посилання нині недоступне.</sub>
- [Тетяна Івашина «Донжуанівський текст як іменний текст культури»](http://dspace.tnpu.edu.ua/handle/123456789/3403):

  > Те ж питання виникає й щодо **елізійського** тексту, породжуючим фактором якого став міфічний **Елізіум**.
  >
  > …Топосні тексти, що, як зазначала Н. Медніс, організуються навколо певної «топологічної структури»; залежно від реальності/фікційності «місця» такі «супертексти» диференціюються як а) локальні (реально існуючі — Петербурзький, Київський, Пермський, Кримський тощо) і б) фік­ційні (серед актуалізованих на сьогоднішній день можна назвати поки що лише **Елізійський**).
- [Український дневник «Свобода», рік XXXII, число 38 (Джерзи Ситі, Н. Дж., второк, 11. марта, 1924), с. 1](https://archive.org/details/Svoboda-1924-058/mode/2up):

  > Париж, 9. марта. — Нині відбулась в **Елізійській** палаті нарада під проводом президента Франції Мільрана, в якій взяли участь премієр Пуанкаре, міністер скарбу Лястейрі і ґубернатор француського державного банку Робіно.

А "сусідська" транскрипція недолуга: біблійний пророк Єлисей не має до Елізіума жодного відношення. І єдиний зв'язок між пророком Єлисеєм (Елішу -> Елісайос -> Elisaeus -> Elisée) та Елізійськими полями (Елісіон -> Elysium -> l’Élysée) - невірне витлумачення назви.

Comment: @AndyKovtun, будь ласка, утримайтеся від сентенцій виду «кого в Ґуґлі забанили». **Don't make me prove your words** ©. Давайте натомість писати self-sustainable answers із посиланнями на джерела. І не посиланням на весь твір цілком, а туди, де це слово вживається. Щоб не доводилося перечитувати всю «Енеїду» заради того, щоб десь знайти підтвердження вашим словам. І посилання надавайте не у коментарях, а прямо у відповіді, будь ласка. Все, що не відповідає критеріям якості, буде видалятися.

Comment: @AndyKovtun такі правила, ви мусите давати відповідь, яка мусить бути самодостатньою

Answer (score 3):

У французькій мові якщо над буквою "е" є значок "é", то ця літера читається як "и". Тобто буде звучати Илізи.
Можете прослухати як це звучить за допомогою перекладача.

Comment: Ще одне слово на букву 'И' )

Comment: Чи можете навести джерела щодо цього?

Answer (score 1):

За вимовою мiжнародним фонетичною абеткою і гісторією слова:

> [фр.](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%89lys%C3%A9e#Nom_propre) Élysée [e.li.ze] — елізе
>   [лат.](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Elysium#la) Elysium [eː.ˈly.si.um] — <sup>е</sup>л<sup>і</sup>сіум.
>   [стр-ґр.](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%A8%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD#Nom_propre) Ἠλύσιον, Êlúsion [ɛː.ˈly.si.on] — <sup>е</sup>л<sup>і</sup>сіон.
>    <sub>Українська не має подовжених голосних та звука [y] — огубленого [і].</sub>

Я не зовсім є шанцєм брати вимову власних ьмен (а тут, схоже, тоь випадок) за зовсім першоџерелом, бо тоді багато імен б писали ся зовсӥм инакше, наприклад *Џони* з *Іванами* б цӧму сенсі не стало б.

Тому маю думку, шчо красше брати забарвєнє нації, котре подекуди привносить і смисленєве:

- *Елізе~ поля* — Паріська маґістраль
- *Елісі~ поля* — Елладська міцолоґія